# Pumping lemma for regular languages

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I have a vey specific question regarding the pumping lemma in the context of regular languages. The theorem states that if $L$ is a regular language, then there exists a constant $n$ such that for every string $w$ in L, with $|w|\geq n$, $w$ can be broken into $w=xyz$ with the following properties:

1. $|y|>0$
2. $|xy|\leq n$
3. For all $k\geq 0$, $xy^kz \in L$

My question concerns the third and first properties. In the third property, does $k=0$ not imply that $|y|=0$, therefore contradicting the first property? 
As far as I can tell, when $k=0 \rightarrow xy^kz=xz$ and, consequently, $y=\epsilon$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

How long is the word "cat"?

If I write "catcat", how long is the word "cat"?

If I write nothing at all, how long is the word "cat"?

Comment: I love the way you explain.

Answer (score 3):

> In the third property, does $k = 0$ not imply that $|y| = 0$ , therefore contradicting the first property?

**No, it does not.**

The third item simply implies $w' = xz \in L$. If $|w'| < n$, then this does not contradict the lemma since it only holds for strings with length at least $n$. On the other hand, if $|w'| \ge n$, it means there are again substrings $x', y', z'$ with the conditions prescribed in the lemma (i.e., $|y'| > 0$, $|x'y'| \le n$, and $x'(y')^k z' \in L$ for all $k \ge 0$), but it *does not at all imply* $x = x'$, $y = y'$, nor $z = z'$, let alone $w' = w$.